# Determining Data Homogeneity/Heterogeneity Using Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a sequential data (i.e., that comes one instance per time). I want to determine for an amount of instances accumulated (after a while), if they are stochastic (i.e., sparse), or homogeneous (i.e., there is some correlation).

To do this I am using a sequential K-means. First, two cluster's centers are given, and the data is sequentially clustered into two classes. After a while, if I observed that the data is sparse between the two clusters, then, I say that is stochastic. However, if I observed that the data is mostly accumulated in one cluster (e.g., 70% of the data), then I say that the data is homogeneous.

**Is my thinking correct?**

Comment: K-means won't give you any significance. Why don't you look at statistical tests? For example, you could use a histogram and use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check for uniform distribution.

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/367089/7828